# Android webview is returning invalid json string from google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, recaptcha

this is my webview settings

```
 domStorageEnabled = true;
 javaScriptEnabled = true;
```

this is my shouldInterceptRequest for web client

```
 val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
            val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url.trim { it <= ' ' })
                .addHeader("X-header", BuildConfig.RESET_USERNAME_PASSWORD_HEADER)
                .build()
            val response: Response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()
            val headers: HashMap<String?, String?> = object : HashMap<String?, String?>() {
                init {
                    put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    put("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
                    put("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
                    put("Content-Type", "*")
                }
            }
 WebResourceResponse(
                    null, "UTF-8",
                    200, "OK", headers, response.body?.byteStream()
                )
```

Log Error

```
 "Uncaught CustomError: Error in protected function: Invalid JSON 
 string: HTTP method GET is not supported by this "
```

So i received an html response instead of json

Is there a webview settings that i missed or request header that i should add besides from Access-Control-Allow-Methods

I also noticed that the recaptcha from webview is keep on loading and calling this url

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6Ldsle8jAAAAALx90hxvqSDQPFW-DdJ4qmqk219K
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to validate the recaptcha through get, which is not allowed. So the response you're trying to return as json, is the error page of the google recaptcha url. 

Try reading up on the docs and use the `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` methods to validate it.

Comment: There is a class for a recaptcha for Android. Why do you need run it in a webview?